# Вывод lambda функции, в виде текста

Tags: php

Приветствую! Знатоки выручайте, долгое время уже пытаюсь разобраться с этим вопросом и никак не могу найти информацию, а точнее нашел, но не то.
Вообщем сама задача.

Есть массив, который содержит в себе lambda функции:

```
$functs = ['name' => function() {
    return 1;
}];
```

Мне нужно создать для него редактирование, казалось бы все так просто, взять циклом пробежаться и всунуть все в input и textarea поля.

Но возникла проблема сами функции они не выводятся так как нужно.
А нужно чтобы они также выводились как определены в массиве, то есть строкой.

```
function() {
    return 1;
}
```

Прям точно также - как и определены в значении массива.
Пробовал делать так:

```
$func= new ReflectionFunction($functs['name']);
var_dump($func->__toString());
```

Но! Выводится мусор, не то, что нужно:

```
Closure [ <user> function {closure} ] {
  @@ .....\index.php 11 - 13
}
```

Уже какой день бьюсь в этом направлении и никак не могу решить задачу, чтобы было ключ массива в input, а значение в textarea.
То есть вот так:
[image: Вывод в поля]

Пожалуйста помогите или пните в правильном направлении.

**UPD:**
Массив может быть любого вида:
Хоть такой:

```
$functs = ['name' => function() {return 1;},'m'=>fucntion() {}];
```

В одну строку.

Пробовал решить так:

```
function closure(Closure $closure) {
    $function = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
    $file = file($function->getFileName());
    for ($i = $function->getStartLine() - 1; $i < $function->getEndLine(); $i++) {
        $str .= $file[$i];
    }
    $funct = mb_substr($str, mb_stripos($str, 'function', 0, 'utf-8'), -1, 'utf-8');
    $funct = mb_substr($funct, 0, mb_strripos($funct, '}', 0, 'utf-8')+1, 'utf-8');
    return $funct;
}
```

Работает, но только если размер массива 1.
То есть такой:

```
$functs = ['name' => function() {return 1;}];
```

а в случае: 
`(new MyClosure($closure))->__toString();`
возникает `LogicException`, что не совсем гуд, исключено, чтобы это было.
нужно решение, чтобы в любом написании массива с lambda функциями.
Кстате, ссылка с приведенным алгоритмом, не пашет тоже.

Незнаю, как поправить свою функцию, так, чтобы отследить правильную позицию завершения блока функции " } ", а не искать конец " } ", а то получается, что он захватывает все и получается хрень.
Похоже и длину строки надо считать и т.д., формула нужна, как верно отследить.
Выручайте, не врублюсь, какое условие написать?

Comment: Похоже можно только вырезать из PHP-файла, выяснив имя файла где определена функция getFileName(), строку с началом getStartLine() и окончанием определения getEndLine().

Comment: Накатай примерчик, пожалуйста, если сможешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось делать запись данных уже в нужном виде (если посоветуете, что-то, лучше, буду рад):

```
public final function arrayDump(array $array): string {
    if (1 <= sizeof($array)) {
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $key = addslashes($key);
            if (is_callable($value)) {
                $value = $this->closure($value);
                $arr[] = "'{$key}' => {$value}";
            } else if (is_string($value)) {
                $arr[] = "'{$key}' => '" . addslashes($value) . "'";
            } else if (is_float($value) || is_double($value)) {
                $value = (double) $value;
                $arr[] = "'{$key}' => {$value}";
            } else if (is_int($value)) {
                $value = (int) $value;
                $arr[] = "'{$key}' => {$value}";
            } else if (is_object($value)) {
                $arr[] = "'{$key}' => '" . serialize($value) . "'";
            }
        }
        return"[\n\t" . join("\t", $arr) . "\n];";
    }
    return'';
}
```

Ну и сам метод closure

```
public final function closure(Closure $closure): string {
    $func = 'function(';
    $function = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
    $params = [];
    $parameters = $function->getParameters();
    foreach ($parameters as $param) {
        $string = '';
        if ($param->isArray()) {
            $string .= 'array ';
        } else if ($param->getClass()) {
            $string .= $param->getClass()->name . ' ';
        }
        if ($param->isPassedByReference()) {
            $string .= '&';
        }
        $string .= '$' . $param->name;
        if ($param->isOptional()) {
            $string .= ' = ' . var_export($param->getDefaultValue(), true);
        }
        $params[] = $string;
    }
    unset($parameters, $param);
    $func .= join(', ', $params) . ') {' . PHP_EOL;
    $lines = file($function->getFileName());
    $start = $function->getStartLine();
    $end = $function->getEndLine();
    for ($l = $start; $l < $end; ++$l) {
        $func .= $lines[$l];
    }
    return $func;
}
```

Теперь нормально работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерчик:

```
class ClosureDump
{
        const SPLITTERS = PHP_EOL . ', ';

        protected $closure;

        protected $begin;
        protected $end;
        protected $file;

        function __construct(\Closure $closure)
        {
            $this->closure = new \ReflectionFunction($closure);
        }

        function __toString()
        {
            $prepared_ary = $this->prepare();
            $dump_ary = explode('=>', $this->trim(array_shift($prepared_ary)));
            $function_ary = array_slice($dump_ary, 1);
            return $this->trim(array_shift($function_ary));
        }

        protected function trim($string)
        {
            return trim($string, self::SPLITTERS);
        }

        protected function prepare()
        {
            $this->file = $this->closure->getFileName();
            $this->begin =  $this->closure->getStartLine() - 1;
            $this->end =  $this->closure->getEndLine();

            return array_slice(file($this->file),
                $this->begin, $this->end - $this->begin);
        }
}
```

**Входные данные:**

```
$functions = [
    'foo' => function() { return 'foo'; },
    'bar' => function() { return 'bar'; },
];
```

**Ну и результат:**

```
echo new ClosureDump($functions['foo']); // => function() { return 'foo'; }
```

**UPD**:

Чуть позже нашел более полноценную [реализацию](http://www.metashock.de/2013/05/dump-source-code-of-closure-in-php/).

**UPD2**:

```
class MyClosure
{
    const EOL = PHP_EOL;
    const TAB =  '  ';

    protected $reflection;
    protected $closure;

    # interface

    public function __construct(\Closure $closure)
    {
        $this->setClosure($closure);
    }

    public function getClosure()
    {
        return $this->closure;
    }

    public function setClosure(\Closure $closure)
    {
        $this->closure = $closure;
        $this->reflection = new \ReflectionFunction($closure);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->buildSignature() .
            $this->buildBody() .
            $this->buildTail();
    }

    # protected

    protected function buildSignature()
    {
        $params = [];

        foreach($this->reflection->getParameters() as $param) {

            $str = '';

            if ($param->isArray()) {
                $str .= 'array ';
            } else if ($param->getClass()) {
                $str .= $param->getClass()->name . ' ';
            }

            if ($param->isPassedByReference()){
                $str .= '&';
            }

            $str .= '$' . $param->name;
            if ($param->isOptional()) {
                $str .= ' = ' . var_export($param->getDefaultValue(), true);
            }

            $params[] = $str;
        }

        $ary = ['function (', implode(', ', $params), ') {' . self::EOL];

        return implode($ary);
    }

    protected function buildBody()
    {
        $reflection = $this->reflection;

        $path = $reflection->getFileName();
        $begin = $reflection->getStartLine();
        $end = $reflection->getEndLine() - 1;

        if ($end > $begin) {
            $ary = array_slice(file($path), $begin, $end - $begin);
        } else {
            throw new \LogicException;
        }

        return implode(array_map(function ($line) {
            return self::TAB . trim($line) . self::EOL;
        }, $ary));
    }

    protected function buildTail()
    {
        return '}';
    }
}


$ary = [
    'foo' => function() {
        return 'foo';
     },
    'bar' => function($foo, $bar, & $baz) {
        $baz = $foo . $bar;
        return $baz;
    },
];

$closure = new myClosure($ary['bar']);
```

Результат вывода `$closure`:

```
function ($foo, $bar, &$baz) {
   $baz = $foo . $bar;
   return $baz;
}
```

После небольшого рефакторинга...

Answer (score 1):

Все ребят всем спасибо, разабрался, теперь работает как надо добавил метод:

```
private function arr(array $array) {
    if(sizeof($array)) {
        $arr = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_callable($value)) {
                $value = new MyClosure($value);
                $value = $value->__toString();
                $arr[] = "'{$key}' => {$value}";
            }
        }
        return'array(' . join(',', $arr) . ');';
    }
    return false;
}
```

И заработало, меняется туда сюда, скрипт-код и сервер по прежнему живет и видно как добавляем и изменяем, Огромнейшее спасибо, без вас бы я не справился ;)

Answer (score 0):

Редактирование норм, но сохранение теперь кривится, сохраняя вида:

```
array(
   'foo'=>
   MyClosure::__set_state(array(
       'reflection'=>
      ReflectionFunction::__set_state(array(
          'name'=>'{closure}',
      )),
       'closure'=>
      Closure::__set_state(array(
      )),
   ))
);
```

Затем при импорте и обращении к функции вылетает крит:

***Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyClosure::__set_state() in ...***

Нужно, чтобы массив имел вид:

```
array(
   'foo'=>function() {
        return 'foo';
     },
);
```

Видимо это так var_export влияет, есть мысли как его обратно записать в файл массив? Вида:

***foo.php***:

```
return array(
  'foo'=>function() {
      return 'foo';
  },
);
```

Конечно можно попробовать дописать костыль, аналог var_export, но может есть другой выход?

Comment: перед сохранением `__toString()` пробовали?

Comment: Да но тогда сохраняет:

return array(
   'a'=>'function () {
   return \'foo\';
}'
); в виде строки. Похоже кроме как писать аналог var_export не получится?

Comment: так, а разве этого не требовалось? если нет, то посмотрите https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure